# Cakephp 2.x and Csrf token

Tags: php, json, cakephp

Im using cakephp 2.x with security component activated, the problem is i disabled csrf verification for my json requests like this :

```
$this->Security->unlockedActions = array('do_json');
```

Is it possible to remove the unlockedActions code from the beforefilter and integrate csrf verification in json requests as well like other not json actions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll most likely have to disable POST data validation, unless your requests would contain data from forms that have been built with the form helper:

```
$this->Security->validatePost = false;
```

And then you have to include the CSRF token in your requests POST data. The generated token can be found in the request parameters as `_Token.key`:

```
$this->request->param('_Token.key')
// or
$this->request->params['_Token']['key']
```

and needs to be submitted as `_Token.key` too, ie

```
{
    "_Token": {
        "key": "keyValue"
    }
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Core Libraries > Controllers > Security > Form tampering prevention > SecurityComponent::$validatePost](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#SecurityComponent::$validatePost)**
- **[Cookbook > Core Libraries > Controllers > Security > CSRF protection > Using CSRF protection](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#using-csrf-protection)**

Comment: But if we have checked manually then how can this token is deleted after successful validation? Because then we delete the token which are used in successful form.

Comment: @BhavinThummar Sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @ndm Sorry for my poor english. Means how can i use validatecsrf function so after call this function that token is expired. I can give you one demo for that if you not understand my question

Comment: @BhavinThummar If you are looking for one-time use tokens, that is the default behavior of the security component, unless you've explicitly changed it via the components `csrfUseOnce` option, see **https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#using-per-session-tokens-instead-of-one-time-use-tokens**. If this isn't what you're looking for, then you may want to open a new question where you can explain your problem in detail, and inlcude code examples.